# How to know the exact amount I'll receive from Apple In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment, storekit

I'm selling products inside my app, that unlock items on my server. Once the purchase is through, my server needs to distribute the incoming money of the purchase to different parties.

The account that I entered on iTunes connect is a EUR account, so everything will be converted to EUR (from what I've understood).

Is there a way for me to know the exact amount I'll receive into my bank account (from the receipt for example), so I can distribute the money correctly, or does Apple simply do a currency conversion at the time of the payment?

Comment: Had the same problem: I created a helper tool: https://showmethe.cash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple does a currency conversion plus tax calculation depending on the country it was purchased in. You can see the exact exchange rate in your payout reports in App Store Connect. More information [from Apple here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3a16f3fe0):

> Sales and Trends estimates the USD amount of sales and proceeds based
>   on a rolling average of the previous month's exchange rates. Final
>   payments in Payments and Financial Reports are based on the exchange
>   rate used to convert each report currency to the currency of your bank
>   account.

Usually, distributing money to users before you get paid from Apple is a risky business model that's open to exploitation. Users could refund their purchases and you'd have no way of knowing until it's too late.

A safer option could be to log the unlocked items and source country the purchase was from on your server, then divide up payouts from Apple when you get them based on these figures. That way, any scammers are distributed across the marketplace as a whole and doesn't come out of your pocket.

Comment: Thank you! So this means that there is no automated way for us to handle this?

Comment: Also: we probably don’t get a transfer for each purchase right? So how do we know where to put the money we receive?

Comment: You can probably automate some of this with the App Store Connect API to export reports: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi